# How to play video and audio files in codeigniter under IE8,9

Tags: php, codeigniter, html5-audio

Firstly I need to thank the SLO for its support.

Currently Iam developing a website where user will upload the audio/video files.Iam saving them in my uploads folder.Now the problem is how can I play those audio and video songs.

**I have checked with the HTML5 audio,video tags but it not playing in all the browsers.**

I too found the pulgins like jplayer in drupal and some other plugins in wordpress for playing audio and video.But how can I do this in codeigniter?

Please help with this.

Thankyou

Comment: what have you tried so far?  I am using html video tag in code igniter on my site hypaquiz.com

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DanyalSandeelo I have used  <audio controls><source src="Bang_Bang.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio> but its not working IE8

Comment: and I know that it only supports from IE9 but I want to play in IE8 also..

Comment: is it working fine in rest of the browsers ?

Comment: Yes I checked with chrome,Firefox

Comment: JWPLAYER will be a good option then but it is not for commercial usage since you might need to buy license

Answer (score 0):

create id there its free http://www.jwplayer.com they will give you script paste it in your html head .

```
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/A7o4ns39EeS3agp+lcGdIw.js"></script>
```

and below script just you can change the file path dynamically it will work i think .or you just paste this code and try

```
   <div id='playerzpumcZwzBZKD'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerzpumcZwzBZKD').setup({
        file: 'http://example.com/media/my_video.mp4',
        image: '//www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
</script>
```